# Best way to prefix all Clarity style rules for inclusion into established project?

Tags: sass, namespaces, prefix, vmware-clarity

I am looking to prefix/namespace all of clarity style rules for inclusion into our current project we are rolling clarity components / styles into. I was wondering what the best & established way to do this is. Should I be looking into PostCss plugins to namespace all of the clarity selectors? Any ideas/examples would be helpful. Presently there are some global collisions (like `.btn`) between clarity and our current codebase. Thank you.

Comment: Which Clarity version does tha app use? As of @clr/ui@latest all clarity styles should be prefixed with `clr-`. If something is missing let us know by filing an issue on github so we can evaluate if it should be prefixed.

Comment: We're currently using the latest - https://github.com/vmware/clarity/tree/v3.0.0-next.4
For example `.btn` but there are also `.modal`, `.card`, `.dropdown`, `.login-wrapper` etc 

I will file an issue. Was the intended goal to have _everything_ prefixed? Is there a mechanism to be able to define your own prefix if warranted in the works?

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2162 exists pertaining to this issue. Will comment there

Comment: Prefixing Clarity CSS would break Clarity, because you have to update the references in HTML as well (some of which are dynamic and in typescript), so the ability to do this is actually quite difficult. This is why we haven't done it yet, the drastic change would break existing applications in a very painful way.

Comment: Does the takeaway then become: best not try to implement Clarity in an established project?

Comment: Maybe not if there are conflicts, but long term we hope to fix this. The problem is it causes a lot of breaking changes so it has to be done carefully.